# Extraordinary string split

Tags: string, algorithm, perl

I have one string

```
my $str = 'one ; two - three; four - five | six - seven; eight ; nine-ten | eleven - twelve | thirteen - fourteen; ';
```

i need to output as seen below

```
one ; two - three; four - five ; eight ; nine-ten            ;
    ;            ; six - seven ;       ; eleven - twelve     ;
    ;            ;             ;       ; thirteen - fourteen ;
```

split fields by ';', and split each by '|' )))
Help me please

Comment: Why can't you just split on `;` into an array then on `|` into another level?  What's the issue?

Comment: @NickT can show code, pls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could achieve your goal:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use List::Util qw(max);

my $str = 'one ; two - three; four - five | six - seven; eight ; nine-ten | eleven - twelve | thirteen - fourteen; ';

my @fields = map { [ split /\s*\|\s*/ ] } split /\s*;\s*/, $str;

my $max_row = max map { scalar(@$_) } @fields;

foreach my $row (0 .. $max_row-1) {
    foreach my $col (@fields) {
        my $width = max map { length ($_) } @$col;
        printf " %-*s ;", $width, $col->[$row] ? $col->[$row] : " ";
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: spaces are apparently significant; in the example output in the question, "; two-three;" does not get a space added after the three.  hmm, but I see fourteen; does get a space added?